# What to use instead "combineLatest2" in RxDart?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, observable, rxdart

After the updating RxDart to 0.23.x you can't use "Observable" class and "combineLatest2" method. So what should I use instead?

Comment: `Rx.combineLatest2` - if you dont know where to find some symbol go to https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/ and type that symbol in top right search field

Answer (score 1):

Use **Rx.combineLatest2** instead of **Observable.combineLatest2**
like:

```
Stream<bool> get submitValid => Rx.combineLatest2(email, password, (email, password) => true);
```